# populate HashMap programatically from collection in Scala

Tags: scala

Given the following:

`mergeMap:HashMap[String,HashSet[String]]`

Why doesn't val x type check to a HashMap[String,Integer] ?

`val x  = HashMap[String,Integer]().withDefault(_ => 1).++( mergeMap.map { case(id,codes) => codes } )`

Instead it type-checks to: scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[Serializable with ScalaObject with 
 Equals]

How can I get it to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: You're appending a bunch of values (without keys) to a collection of pairs (key, value), why should it work? Moreover, you're trying to combine integers with HashSets of strings.

Comment: Oh come on don't downvote me you guys.  You'll hurt my walrussy feelings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but is it something like this?

```
    scala> val mergeMap = Map(("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value1"))
    mergeMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2, key3 -> value1)

    scala> mergeMap.values.toSet.map((_ : String, 1)).toMap
    res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(value1 -> 1, value2 -> 1)
```

The first one makes a map from String to String (not from String to a Collection of Strings like in your example).

The second one takes all the values from the map, and builds a new map with the values from the first map as keys and the default value 1 as each value. Duplicate keys are discarded (in the "toSet" step and would be discarded again in the "toMap" step).

Comment: HashMap[String,Integer]().++(mergeMap.values.flatten.map((_:String, 1:Integer)).toMap)

Comment: It's based on your answer, you should put it up.  Thanks!